# How to enable windows 8 installed in VM Virtual box to use the laptop's build-in web camera

Tags: virtualization, windows-8, integrated-camera

How to enable the laptop's build-in web camera, to be available on windows 8 installed in VM Virtual box. My web cam is working fine in windows 7(host). For my linux VM box it works fine as well. Any suggestion?

Comment: 'build-it' or built in?

Answer (score 3):

I would assume the producedure is the [same as for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/4939/34265):

> 1. Make sure the virtual machine is not running and your webcam is not being used.
> 2. Bring up the main VBox window and in the details tab for your Win7 machine click USB.
> 3. Make sure "Enable USB Controller" is selected. Also make sure that "Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller" is selected too.
> 4. Click the "Add filter from device" button (the cable with the '+' icon).
> 5. Select your device from the list.
> 6. Now click OK and start your VM.

Comment: it is laptop's integrated webcamera. I don't remember installing any drivers either.

Comment: @Avatar: Even integrated devices can (and often do) use the USB infrastructure. Does it not list anything?

Comment: no, under USB only "Standard OpenHCD USB Host Controller" and "USB Root Hub" were listed.

Comment: @Avatar: In that case, I'm not aware of another way.